# Estimate overnight returns for many stocks using a for loop and store it in a dataframe with stock names as column names

Tags: r, rename, xts

I am trying to estimate overnight returns for many stocks using a for loop and store it in a dataframe with stock names as column names. The `trade` has raw intraday data and `trade2` has cleaned intraday data. `list.namess` has stock names.  This is my code:

```
require(xts)
require(highfrequency)
OvernightRet<-list()
list.namess<- list.files(pattern="*.IS Equity")
list.namess<- list.namess[2]
for(Q in 1:length(list.namess)){
  trade<-readRDS(list.namess[Q])
  trade<-xts(trade[,-1], order.by = trade[,1])
  colnames(trade)[c(1,2)]<-c("PRICE", "SIZE")
  #Unduplicating
  trade2<-do.call(rbind, lapply(split(trade,"days"), mergeTradesSameTimestamp))
  trade2<-trade2[,1]

  fun.first= function(x) first(x)
  fun.last= function(x) last(x)
  A=do.call(rbind, lapply(split(trade2, "days"), FUN=fun.first))
  B=do.call(rbind, lapply(split(trade2, "days"), FUN=fun.last))
  OvernightRetA <- (as.numeric(A)-as.numeric(lag.xts(B)))/as.numeric(lag.xts(B))
  colnames(OvernightRetA)<-list.namess[Q]
  OvernightRet[[Q]]<-OvernightRetA
}
df.OvernightRet<-do.call(merge, OvernightRet)
```

However, it gives error, probably because of not being able to rename the OvernightRetA:

```
    Error in `colnames<-`(`*tmp*`, value = "ACEM IS Equity.rds") : 
      attempt to set 'colnames' on an object with less than two dimensions
    In addition: There were 50 or more warnings (use warnings() to see the first 50)
    > df.OvernightRet<-do.call(merge, OvernightRet)

Error in as.data.frame(x) : argument "x" is missing, with no default
```

As trade and trade2 is huge and not appropriate for dput. I am posting given Open(A), Close(B) and list of names (list.namess) for reproducibility of error.

```
dput(head(A,10))
structure(c(231.9, 236.35, 230, 226.85, 229.05, 225.7, 226.95, 
224.55, 227, 234.65), class = c("xts", "zoo"), .indexCLASS = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt"), .indexTZ = "Asia/Calcutta", tclass = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt"), tzone = "Asia/Calcutta", Price = 1L, index = structure(c(1459481850, 
1459741066, 1459827433, 1459913867, 1460000236, 1460086630, 1460345867, 
1460432285, 1460518631, 1460950628), tzone = "Asia/Calcutta", tclass = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt")), .Dim = c(10L, 1L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, "PRICE"))


dput(head(B,10))
structure(c(235.35, 231.2, 226.1, 229.05, 226.45, 225.75, 224.55, 
223.75, 231.1, 228.6), class = c("xts", "zoo"), .indexCLASS = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt"), .indexTZ = "Asia/Calcutta", tclass = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt"), tzone = "Asia/Calcutta", Price = 1L, index = structure(c(1459508732, 
1459767943, 1459854348, 1459940748, 1460027143, 1460113538, 1460374518, 
1460465873, 1460545568, 1460977541), tzone = "Asia/Calcutta", tclass = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt")), .Dim = c(10L, 1L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, "PRICE"))

dput(list.namess) "ACEM IS Equity.rds"
```

Kindly help me solve this error.

Comment: What is the error you are getting? Include the exact error message. Make sure your sample data reproduces the exact same error you are getting.

Comment: @MrFlick, Greetings, As I have mentioned trade and trade2 are very large datasets, not appropriate for dput. Do you think the code for overnight returns code lines14-17 are fine?

Comment: The error implies `OvernightRetA` is not a matrix or data.frame so it doesn't have columns so you can't set `colnames()`. You didn't spend any time saying what the desired output is or what you are trying to do so it's unclear what you want to happen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the problem, as the error message implies, is that you are trying to assign a column header to a single value. You can work around this by changing the line above to:

`OvernightRetA <- as.data.frame(as.numeric(A)-as.numeric(lag.xts(B)))/as.numeric(lag.xts(B))`

Comment: Thanks aakash, this will give problem during df.OvernightRet<-do.call(merge, OvernightRet)

Comment: I see. Why not store the stock name and return value as rows in a dataframe while in the loop, and then transpose using `t()` after the loop has completed? Store stock_name in col1, value in col2

Comment: Dear aakash this is the error: > df.OvernightRet<-do.call(merge, OvernightRet)
Error in as.data.frame(y) : argument "y" is missing, with no default

Comment: What you sugeest in your 2nd comment seems good. Kindly show in the answer